# How to set Social Profile Properties while creation of new contact

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In my app i`m creating a  ABRecordRef instance and creating a new contact. So I tried these lines of codes for setting the social profile iD's

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef fbvalue = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(fbvalue, (__bridge CFTypeRef)[linedevidebydel objectAtIndex:linedevidebydel.count - 1], kABPersonSocialProfileServiceFacebook, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonSocialProfileProperty, fbvalue,nil);
            CFRelease(fbvalue);
```

but getting an error in the last line

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17631380'
```

could any one please help me... Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to use dictionary with property as social profile property, use like this,

```
   ABMutableMultiValueRef multiSocial =  ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
   NSMutableDictionary *socialDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; //use this for other profile, twitter, linkedIn , etc 

  [socialDictionary setObject:@"happy.coding@ymail.com" forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonSocialProfileServiceFacebook];

  ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiSocial, socialDictionary, kABPersonSocialProfileServiceFacebook, NULL);
  ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiSocial,&error);
```

hope this helps u